# When row is added it should keep all formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to add a row which keep the formulas.

But when i add any row it always empty.

I could not found a way by searching on google.

I have attached below example sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciate

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HiOrz1KAuV1nN9a2IlwQgv3aWrGNKFaKHq2a8JZw3gI/edit#gid=0

Comment: can you show your existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to copy the formulas to the newly inserted row **upon inserting** a new row.

- You can use an [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) which has a property `INSERT_ROW` and
  make sure you activate some code when you insert a new row.
- The following script will copy the content and formulas from the above row of the one which was inserted to the newly inserted row upon inserting a new row.

### Solution:

Add both code snippets below to the script editor:

```
function myFunction(e) {
 const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
     const row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow(); 
     var fromRng = sh.getRange(row-1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
     var toRng = sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
     fromRng.copyTo(toRng);
  }
}
```

and **execute** this function `createTrigger` **only** and **once** to create the `onChange` trigger:

```
function createTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

### Illustration:

[image]

### Limitation:

- The disadvantage of this approach is that is copies both values and formulas, but it does not seem to matter in your case since you have only formulas as of now. If you want to put only formulas you need to use [setFormulaR1C1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula) but since you have cells with no formulas, you need to make sure that you copy formulas, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. @Marios can you please see the again above attached file, i have added some values to the row and tried to make new row by that it gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This should let you copy your last row, including data and formula, into its next row.

```
function addRow() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lastCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var range = sh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, lastCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

The important parameter you need in `copyTo` here is `{contentsOnly:false}`. Feel free to modify the coordinates for you to paste the row to anywhere.

For more details, read the [usage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean)) of `copyTo`

If you want only the formula in the newly added row, you need to get the formula from the source row and then copy it to your destination row.

```
var source = sheet.getRange("A1:C1");
var dest = sheet.getRange("A2:C2");
var arr = source.getFormulas();
dest.setFormulas(arr);
```

This doesn't adjust the formula to the new row, it will copy the exact cell formula so be careful.

Comment: NaziA, Thank you for your suggestion, But i want to apply this on complete spreadsheet and on all number of sheets. It also should be automatic when i add row then formula should be added as available in attached sheet.

Comment: Before I was able to formulate the trigger, Marios already posted his answer. That should do the trick :) @Learning

Comment: @NaziA sorry for posting after your answer (I voted up yours). When there are codeless questions are very easy to be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Hi @Marios, no problem. I understand what you mean, that's why I was only able to post an incomplete answer. Kudos to you for going beyond  and providing a complete and accurate answer